# Como calcular el índice de Gini para variables categóricas?

Tags: python, indices, categorical

Me gustaría calcular el índice de Gini en **python** con variables categóricas. Vi este código que podría servirme para reciclar:

```
def gini(x):
# (Warning: This is a concise implementation, but it is O(n**2)
# in time and memory, where n = len(x).  *Don't* pass in huge
# samples!)

# Mean absolute difference
mad = np.abs(np.subtract.outer(x, x)).mean()
# Relative mean absolute difference
rmad = mad/np.mean(x)
# Gini coefficient
g = 0.5 * rmad
return g
```

Tengo datos con **zonas visitadas por personas** por ejemplo:

- persona 1: [zona2, zona4, zona5, zona2, zona2]
- persona 2 [zona1, zona5, zona4, zona1, zona1, zona3]
- persona 3 [zona3, zona3, zona3, zona1, zona3]

y quiero saber que tan dispersa (o poco dispersa) esta esa persona dependiendo de las zonas que visite en un parámetro de 0 a 1.
Entonces, quiero obtener que la persona 3 está menos dispersa que la persona 1.
Creo que el valor 0 de este parámetro representa menos dispersión.
Para hacer eso, creo que el índice de Gini representa eso, pero mis variables (zonas) son categóricas.

¿Sabes cómo puedo resolver esto?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. El idioma oficial es español, así que debo pedirte que traduzcas toooooooooooooda la pregunta (incluyendo el título!) 
para que otros te respondan y para que no termine cerrada. 
Recuerda que puedes [edit] la pregunta todas las veces que quieras.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Gracias por editar! Siguiente paso indicado en Cómo preguntar según el enlace que te compartí: Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio. No sabemos en qué lenguaje estás haciendo ésto, por ejemplo. Suelen usarse las etiquetas para indicarlo. Pero sobre todo, es importante trabajar sobre tu código y tus errores/problemas.